# Issue while using channels: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to understand how channels work. I have this example:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func greet(c chan string) {
    fmt.Println("1: " + <-c)
    fmt.Println("2: " + <-c)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")

    c := make(chan string, 1)

    go greet(c)
    c <- "John"

    c <- "Mike"
    c <- "Mary"
    fmt.Println("active goroutines", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    c <- "Edward"
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

While executing the above code, I see that its giving an error "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!". But as per my understanding, the execution should get blocked after "Edward" is sent to the channel.

```
c <- "Edward"
```

and this program should have printed out Mary and Edward values. I am also not closing this channel anywhere. Can anyone tell me why, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Running this code on the playground shows that your understanding is correct. https://play.golang.org/p/wh2yqht6Snt

Comment: Your code prints only John and Mike because your goroutine has only two print statements each with one channel receive. Why would you expect it to print anything more? Furthermore you can send Mary without crashing your program because you're using a buffered channel of size 1, and you can't send Edward anymore as there is no more code to first receive Mary, if you changed the size to 2 you would be able to send Edward as well without needing to add a receive and your program would not crash, however Mary and Edward would still not be printed, since you haven't written any code to do that.

Comment: @mkopriva So does that mean that once all code inside greet() function is executed completely, it will stop running?

Comment: Yes, just like any other function. The `go` keyword does not mean "run this function indefinitely" if that's what you were thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following code so that you understand it better. I've added comments as well. Although, @mkopriva cleared your doubts, but I thought it'd be better if I post the commented code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func greet(c chan string) {
    // Range over the channel until close() is called
    for r := range c {
        // Print the names
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan string, 1) // Make a bufferred channel with capacity of 1
    go greet(c)               // Spawn the goroutine
    c <- "John"               // Send
    c <- "Mike"               // Send
    c <- "Mary"               // Send
    c <- "Edward"             // Send
    close(c)                  // Close the channel which signals the for loop
    // inside greet to stop receiving
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // Let us give the main gorutine some time
    // before it exits so that it lets the greet() to recieve all the names.
    // But it's better to use sync.WaitGroup for this.
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

Comment: @sonal Could you please mark the solution as accepted? Otherwise, the question remains in the unanswered section. It just helps the community in findings the relevant answers quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your Problem is pretty simple.
If you put something in a channel, you have to somehow get it back out.
The function `greet(c chan string)` does not run infinitely when you just put a "go" in front of it. It just means that the function is calling a new go routine to run in.
The code you wrote produces a deadlock because the function got terminated after it ranged over the channel.

```
go greet(c)
c <- "John"
c <- "Mike"
//all these things happen at the same time
```

When you put something in a channel that can't get out again you create a Deadlock. The thread tries to put something in a channel that has no consumer anymore.

The solution is also very simple. Just loop over the channel. That way it ranges over the channel until its closed.

```
func greet(c chan string) {
    for name := range c {
        fmt.Println(name)
    }
}
```